# Can we transfer questions from SO to meta?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, migration

For example, I have two questions which should be transferred:

- [What would you want to see in a StackOverflow API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/350248)
- [Is there a guide to accessing StackOverflow data programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/282179)

(The latter should be updated now that the data dump is available, of course.)

Is there a facility for this in place? Is there going to be?

EDIT: I suspect the [Jon Skeet facts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/305223/jon-skeet-facts) question would be more apprpropriate here, too :)

Comment: I suggested it [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2143)

Comment: What about links? Would they follow from one site to other if a question is moved?

Comment: How is this completed? The first question is closed but it was not transferred, I think they should be migrated if they were closed prior to the implementation

Comment: Since this question is specifically about meta-oriented questions that existed on SO before MSO was created, instead of being about migration in general, it seems too localized now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I expect that this will eventually be possible, just as it's possible to transfer between SO and SF. The only thing is that (afaik) post ownership is currently lost for users that don't have an account on the site being transfered to, so even if the user subsequently signed up, it's currently not possible for them to regain ownership.

Comment: Why is the ownership lost if the account does exists in both websites ?

Comment: I've taken a closer look at this and if a user has an account on both sites, the ownership is preserved. However, I don't know if a user that does not have an account on the site that their post is transferred to, but later creates an account, will then be given ownership of the post. Maybe a hidden account is created if one doesn't already exist so that when the user does sign up they just sign into that account, but I don't know for sure. It's probably less of a problem here as Jeff has migrated over most of the SO accounts, but those with only a Google OpenID might be out of luck.

Comment: Also worth bearing in mind that account migration doesn't always work, especially with those of us using google...

Comment: I think this problem is solved, and you can associate accounts with each other even using Google OpenID (or any other where id depends on site name). Also you can use secondary OpenID provider (I used Technorati) which is the same for both accounts.

Answer (score 2):

I asked this very question here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/189/should-there-be-an-option-to-move-questions-between-so-sf-here-and-su-when-it. But as is often the way Jon Skeet got in there first.

Comment: OK, I closed your question and linked to this one. That way discussion stays focused in one place.

Comment: Cheers - I did the first bit (both ways) but didn't get round to the closing.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to put my 2 cents in by saying that ownership preservation of questions and account transfers are very important and needs to be done "right". It would be a disservice to the community if moving between the sites was at all painful.

I think that the SO team will do a good job with this, but we will see.

Comment: We're working on it now :)

Comment: Perhaps there should be some warning if you want to move your question, and you don't have accounts associated? _(Just a thought)_

Answer (score 0):

It'd be nice to have a link to the meta.SO question too so we can jump to the meta discussion and post answers there.