# What is the right way to make a feature request?

Tags: feature-request

What exactly is the right way to propose a feature request and its implementation? Obviously, the main idea, overview, background, and the like should go in the question, but how about a proposed way of doing it? Should it be:

1. Included in the question body? It's all part of your original idea, so keep it together. Let people propose new ways as answers or comment as appropriate.

   or
2. Included as a separate answer? This keeps with the question-answer model of the site and lets people vote individually on your ideas.

If #2 is the right way, how should reputation be handled? Should you post your ideas as community wiki to let people freely vote? Or is it ok for you to gain reputation twice, once for the feature and once for the implementation?

Comment: Odd. I marked this community wiki since it was a meta-meta, but it didn't stick?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is #1, keep it all together. Though StackOverflow and ServerFault stricly require the question/answer model, the rules have been relaxed here. The reason the site still says things like "question" and "answer" is because it's going to take a little time to make the necessary changes toward a more [discussion-oriented](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/cmon-get-meta/) site.

Incidentally, this does not mean that questions will no longer be allowed or even no longer be the predominant method of starting a topic, just that other forms of discussion will also be permitted.

Answer (score 3):

I think it should be separated out into problem - solution. Too often when people make feature requests they don't state what the real problem they are trying to solve is, just the solution they want to solve it. It's also common that the initially proposed solution is impractical or non-optimal. Allowing the solution to be rated alongside other solutions allows for a better exploration of the solution domain.

Comment: This would work for some feature requests, but for many the problem and solution are the same. Take http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96/can-we-transfer-questions-from-so-to-meta as an example. The problem is that some questions on SO belong here on Meta. The solution is to move them over. The only thing to discuss is the merit of the request, as there aren't any alternative solutions.

Comment: @Sam: I agree.  As a developer I don't want people telling me how to solve a problem but I do want them to tell me exactly what their problem is so I can solve it in the best way I can.  It also irks me when someone claims that a certain solution needs to be provided when actually it is a certain underlying problem that must be solved.