# SE Sites that are not programming related show “what’s your programming question? be specific.”

Tags: bug, status-norepro, area-51, stack-exchange

On the new Area 51 sites, it shows "what's your programming question? be specific."

Can this be changed to "what's your question? be specific".

Related to [When you ask a question it says "What's your programming question?"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96/when-you-ask-a-question-it-says-whats-your-programming-question) but does not seem to be fixed for the Area 51 sites.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not seeing this. I just went on a round trip through Gaming, Photography, Programmers, and Board & Card Games (2 live, 2 beta). All of them just say "what's your question? be specific".

[image]

Part of me thinks this might be the same issue [that an individual on Gaming once experienced](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1331/please-change-the-default-text-for-title-textbox-of-the-question), in which the watermark wasn't actually a problem but a matter of auto-complete. In which case, it isn't an issue on the Stack Exchange end. Could this be the same for you?

Comment: You are absolutely correct. It never crossed my mind that this is the case. I cleared my cache and all is well. Thanks anyways :)

Comment: Freehand *lines*? What were you thinking?